# When are "vampires" first mentioned in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, vampire

So, we have the vampire Sanguini who is briefly seen in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*.

> “Harry, I’d like you to meet Eldred Worple, an old student of
>   mine, author of Blood Brothers: My Life Amongst the Vampires —
>   and, of course, his friend Sanguini.”
>
> "Sanguini, stay here!” added Worple, suddenly stern, for
>   **the vampire** had been edging toward the nearby group of girls, a
>   rather hungry look in his eye.

I haven't perused *The Philosopher's Stone* or *The Chamber of Secrets* (thoroughly) for quite a while, and I'm interested to know **if there are any references or appearances of Rowling-vampires in there, or if Sanguini *is* the first mention of Rowling's concept of vampires.**

Comment: Quirrell was looking for vampires before PS. I think Hagrid mentions it?

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28433/4918 where my question lists some of the times vampires are mentioned in Harry Potter.

Comment: In the Leaky Cauldron

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The earliest *mention* is in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone Chapter 5: Diagon Alley.

> ‘What sort of magic do you teach, Professor Quirrell?’ ‘D-Defence Against the D-D-Dark Arts,’ muttered Professor Quirrell, as though he’d rather not think about it. ‘N-not that you n-need it, eh, P-P-Potter?’ He laughed nervously. ‘You’ll be g-getting all your equipment, I suppose? **I’ve g-got to p-pick up a new b-book on vampires, m-myself.’** He looked terrified at the very thought.

We learn in Chapter 3 of Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban that Harry has seen a *picture* of a vampire in his DADA class.

> Harry looked into the shadowed eyes of Sirius Black, the only part of
>   the sunken face that seemed alive. Harry had never met a vampire, but
>   he had seen pictures of them in his Defence Against the Dark Arts
>   classes, and Black, with his waxy white skin, looked just like one.

As you say, the first time that he actually encounters one is in HP and the Half-Blood Prince

Comment: Good call, I had forgotten that he said he was going to get a book on them before Hagrid's mention of them

Comment: Do we know that he saw the picture during book three? That second quote doesn't say when he saw the picture.

Comment: @ibid - I've edited accordingly. You're right. He might have seen one in a previous year.

Comment: Makes me wonder if vampires in the Harry Potter world can be seen by mirrors unlike the real world mythology. This would be required for a photograph to be taken. Unless the picture here is referring to is an illustration but then I suspect you couldn't see the "waxy skin".

Comment: @DasBeasto There could absolutely be illustrations that show waxy skin, at least if they're in color. And maybe you can photograph vampires with a pinhole-type camera?

Comment: @MissMonicaE normal cameras don't use mirrors to actually take the picture (if you were using a [D]SLR you wouldn't be able to see them through the viewfinder but there isn't any mirrors between vampire and film/sensor) so a pinhole wouldn't make any difference

Comment: It's also possible that wizards can enchant mirrors / cameras to be able to pick up vampires. We never hear so in the books but we also barely hear anything about vampires.

Answer (score 14):

Vampires are mentioned in Harry Potter and the Sorcerers Stone

In Chapter 5 Hagrid says the following when talking to Harry about Professor Quirrell

> 'They say he met vampires in the Black Forest and there was a nasty bit o' trouble with a hag – never been the same since.'

There was also mention in Chapter 8 that his classroom smelled strongly of garlic supposedly to ward off a Vampire he'd met in Romania.

Comment: They're mentioned, but this isn't the ***first*** mention.