# Did vampires ever fight for Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, vampire, death-eaters

As seen in this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28433/65246) vampires are mentioned several times in the Harry Potter books.

1. Hagrid mentions Professor Quirrell met vampires in the Black Forest.
2. One of Lockhart's books is titled Voyages with Vampires.
3. Lupin assigns an essay on vampires.
4. Slughorn invites vampires to his party where Harry meets one.

From these points, it is understandable that the vampires exist in the Harry Potter universe, wizards have good knowledge about them and some of the wizards have even befriended them.

When Voldemort rose to power for the second time he allied with giants, werewolves, Dementors and various other creatures. However, I could not find any mention of vampires allying with him. Did he get any vampires to fight for him?

Comment: Some useful(ish) info here; https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vampires

Comment: @Valorum That is some great info. Thanks.

Comment: The wiki doesn't seem to offer anything useful; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire

Comment: Do they sparkle in the sunlight too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Vampires played no meaningful part, implying they didn’t aid him.

While it’s theoretically possible that the Dark Lord had vampire allies that were never seen, as there’s no explicit statement that no vampires worked with the Dark Lord, the evidence is against it. Though Rowling’s never explicitly said that no vampires worked with the Dark Lord, she *does* state in her writing on Pottermore about vampires that they played no meaningful part in the story.

> Although vampires exist in the world of Harry Potter, as shown by the literature that Harry and his friends study in Defence Against the Dark Arts, they play no meaningful part in the story. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Vampires (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vampires)*</sup></sub>

Since presumably working for or being allies of the Dark Lord would be considered a meaningful part in the story, this very likely means that no vampires were working with the Dark Lord.

## Vampires as a species mightn’t be inclined to join the Dark Lord.

The creatures that join the Dark Lord tend to be evil, shunned by wizard society, or a bit of both. Vampires aren’t shown as being particularly evil or being shunned as a whole by wizard society (like werewolves are) so they probably wouldn’t be particularly interested in joining the Dark Lord. Neither of the vampires mentioned seem to be evil or particularly bad. Sanguini was a friend of Slughorn’s old student, and Slughorn trusted him enough to bring him to a party.

> “Worple, who was a small, bespectacled man, grabbed Harry’s hand and shook it enthusiastically; the vampire Sanguini, who was tall and emaciated with dark shadows under his eyes, merely nodded. He looked rather bored. A gaggle of girls was standing close to him, looking curious and excited.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 15 (The Unbreakable Vow)*</sup></sub>

He does eye some humans hungrily, but he’s easily distracted by a pasty. Though Trocar never actually showed up in the books, he was going to be a teacher at Hogwarts whose subject wasn’t decided (meaning it wasn’t for sure Defense Against the Dark Arts, the only subject with a few evil teachers), and Rowling only mentioned him as being a teacher, so most likely he wasn’t intended to be evil either. Vampires don’t seem to be shunned either - people seem excited to see Sanguini. Notably, Honeydukes seems to sell candy for vampires, indicating they’re not particularly shunned.

> “Ron and Hermione were standing underneath it, examining a tray of blood-flavoured lollipops. Harry sneaked up behind them.
> ‘Urgh, no, Harry won’t want one of those, they’re for vampires, I expect,’ Hermione was saying.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 10 (The Marauder’s Map)*</sup></sub>

Honeydukes, a ‘normal’ wizarding candy store, being willing to serve them shows that vampires are accepted or likely at least tolerated by wizarding society, and since they don’t seem to be evil, it’s unlikely that they’d have much reason to want to join the Dark Lord.

## No vampires are ever mentioned as fighting for the Dark Lord.

There are several creatures who are mentioned as either the Dark Lord trying to recruit them, or as fighting for him. However, there’s no mention of him or his Death Eaters ever pursuing or having vampires on their side, despite alliances with other creatures being explicitly mentioned. The Dark Lord says he expects the Dementors and giants to join him, and he’ll have an army of creatures.

> “The Dementors will join us … they are our natural allies … we will recall the banished giants … I shall have all my devoted servants returned to me, and an army of creatures whom all fear …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Both the giants (except Grawp) and the Dementors did join him, as shown later, and they weren’t the only ones. Greyback, a werewolf, was working for the Dark Lord. In addition to his using brute force to fight for the Dark Lord, Greyback was also helping him get *other* werewolves to join him.

> “And this is the man Voldemort is using to marshal the werewolves. I cannot pretend that my particular brand of reasoned argument is making much headway against Greyback’s insistence that we werewolves deserve blood, that we ought to revenge ourselves on normal people.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 16 (A Very Frosty Christmas)*</sup></sub>

However, there’s no mention whatsoever of either the Dark Lord or the Death Eaters on his behalf trying to recruit vampires, or of any vampires who already joined him. It seems likely that if he had or even had tried to get vampire allies, it would have been mentioned at least once. No vampires come to fight for him at Hogwarts, though giants, Dementors, and at least one werewolf do. As that was his most important battle, it seems likely he’d want every creature allied with him to fight for him there, so that no vampires were at Hogwarts then implies that he didn’t have any.

Comment: Indeed it would be a significant thing to note if they fought with the Dark Lord. Also there's this to consider: when Hagrid &c tells the trio who they've been trying to recruit (Lupin goes underground trying to get werewolves to join their side; Hagrid and - I can't remember the spelling of her name - try and get the giants to join their side etc.). Of course it could be argued that the Order didn't know of any vampires but that in my mind suggests something else: they weren't relevant to the battle. If they were relevant would't the Order and also Death Eaters be talking about them?

Comment: @Pryftan Agreed, them helping the Dark Lord would likely be considered significant. That’s a good point as well - neither side ever mentioned trying to recruit vampires, though it was explicitly mentioned the efforts on both sides to convince the giants and the werewolves. It is possible they didn’t know of any vampires to attempt to recruit. However, I agree with you and think it’s most likely that they either weren’t relevant or weren’t thought as being recruitable to the battle. As no one shows any interest in them, it’s unlikely either side viewed them as potential allies to be recruited.

Comment: Yes. Also have to consider that Rowling did a lot of work and paid attention to details. She (Pottermore writing?) said that she actually learnt some about chemistry so she would have a better idea on potions. The fact she didn't really get into vampires and she also said they played no significant role makes me certain that they absolutely did not help either side. But not only were they not mentioned by either side they weren't mentioned in any of the battles either. As for contacting me I updated my profile here with an email I just made (can send real email from there).

Comment: The fact that other creatures that joined Voldemort are generally hated by the wizard community unlike vampires is a considerable reason.

Comment: @KolappanNathan Thanks a lot - I think so as well! :)

Comment: @Miss Bella Looking forward to it! :) Deleted my other comment as it's really OT; but I have another comment on the answer/question: Werewolves and Dementors are significant figures in the story. But are there other creatures that all things considered (at least wrt battles) insignificant but mentioned in the final battle? Yes! The house elves (Kreacher leading them in battle praising not just Harry but also his beloved Regulus). The centaurs (after Hagrid guilt trips them) also participate. If vampires participated Rowling would have mentioned them too! Incontrovertible don't you think? I do.

Comment: @Pryftan Okay, awesome! :) I’ll be around whenever!

Comment: @Miss Bella I deleted the OT comments just now. I also had another thought: There is that fan theory that Severus was a vampire; Rowling has flatly said otherwise. In addition she did say that with the Inferi she wanted them to not be like the typical zombies in modern literature (I can't say I blame her even if zombies didn't annoy me so very much). All the types of creatures and all the sides were mentioned explicitly so absolutely no vampires were part of the conflict. Another thought: maybe vampires are rather rare or they shun society or...

Comment: @Miss Bella You might also comment on the Pm writing: *The vampire myth is so rich, and has been exploited so many times in literature and on film, that **I felt there was little I could add** to the tradition. In any case, **vampires are a tradition of Eastern Europe, and in general I tried to draw from British mythology and folklore** when creating adversaries for Harry.* This is even more evidence that vampires weren't on either side. (Though I just noticed padfoot's answer talks about this but knowing you you could add something interesting on it.)

Answer (score 4):

**It's doubtful.** Since there are no quotes that explicitly say no vampires ever worked for Voldemort there is still a chance though it is slim. Here are a few quotes from Pottermore telling us about vampires,

> Although vampires exist in the world of Harry Potter, as shown by the literature that Harry and his friends study in Defence Against the Dark Arts, they play no meaningful part in the story. The vampire myth is so rich, and has been exploited so many times in literature and on film, that I felt there was little I could add to the tradition. In any case, vampires are a tradition of Eastern Europe, and in general I tried to draw from British mythology and folklore when creating adversaries for Harry. Aside from passing mentions, therefore, the only vampire whom Harry meets in the books is Sanguini in Half-Blood Prince, who makes a faintly comic appearance at a party.
> <sub><sup>-[*Vampires - Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vampires)</sup></sub>

In this quote we cans see that the only (that isn't only briefly mentioned) vampire in the Harry Potter series is Sanguini.

> Looking back through my earliest notebooks, however, I found that on my very earliest list of staff, there was a subjectless vampire teacher I had forgotten, called ‘Trocar’. A Trocar is sharply pointed shaft inserted into arteries or cavities to extract bodily fluids, so I think it a rather good name for a vampire. Evidently I did not think much of him as a character, though, because he disappears fairly early on in my notes.
> <sub><sup>-[*Vampires - Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vampires)</sup></sub>

So there is one other vampire that was removed from the series but he didn't work for Voldemort.

> For a long time there was a persistent fan rumour that Snape might be a vampire. While it is true that he has an unhealthy pallor, and is sometimes described as looking like a large bat in his long black cloak, he never actually turns into a bat, we meet him outside the castle by daylight, and no corpses with puncture marks in their necks ever turn up at Hogwarts. In short, Snape is not a revamped Trocar.
> <sub><sup>-[*Vampires - Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vampires)</sup></sub>

If there are any suspicions about Snape, they are untrue. The only creatures we **know** Voldemort recrutied are the Giants and the Dementors

> “The Dementors will join us … they are our natural allies … we will recall the banished giants … I shall have all my devoted servants returned to me, and an army of creatures whom all fear …”
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

**So in conclusion there are no vampires in Voldemort's employment that we know of.**

Comment: After going through your answer and wikia links from Valorum I agree with you. Unless J.K. Rowling confirms the involvement of vampires this will hold good. I'll wait  sometime for more responses before accepting your answer.

Comment: ok, i also looked through wiki sites (though i frown on them) and couldnt find any reference of Voldemorts army having vampires even from them. Thanks!

Comment: erfffffffff i screwed up my editing and cant find out what i did: on the last quote the chapter source is too big, anone help?

Comment: @padfoot - You had </sup> twice on the line above

Comment: wow im unobservant :/ thanks.

Comment: @padfoot Don't look at it that way. Maybe you are but it's not necessarily true. I'm extremely observant and am always aware of my surroundings from all angles. I can't stand when people are behind me or in front of me or beside me too close. I also pay attention to details very carefully and it's a key part of my ability to have a comment for most everything (whether reply to something said or otherwise). Yes these types of things are easy to miss. Maybe you were tired, maybe you were distracted... These things are very easy to miss no matter how observant you are. Don't think bad on yourself

Comment: @padfoot **Giants and the Dementors** You might also add that he also recruited werewolves. The Order tried to recruit both the Giants and Werewolves but they failed there; Dumbledore even points out that the way they were treated would have devastating effects later on: and those effects are that they preferred working for the Dark Lord and his Death Eaters.